# Does several PIC12F683 pull-ups cause short circuit

Tags: pic, pullup

I am connecting several PICs together by GP4 and GP5 pins, and I used their internal pull-ups to make pins high by default. If in all PICs pull-ups are enabled. Does connecting a lot of PICs together (i.e. 25 PICs) makes a low pull-up that causes short circuit when one pin in one PIC became low? Do I need to disable pull-up and simply use two resistors for all PICs?

Comment: Please improve your question. (1) Are you connecting inputs or outputs or outputs to inputs? (2) If inputs: what is driving the inputs and why do you need the pull-ups? (3) If outputs: what stops different outputs pulling different directions (high and low)?

Comment: All are inputs, the PIC that want to send data to others changes its pins to output, sends data, and again changes pins to input.

Comment: Be careful with that. If 2 PIC's change to output at the same time an one sends a 1 (5V) and the other a 0 (0V) you have a direct short from 5V to ground on your dataline and you will most probably burn both PIC's. Make sure this can never happen!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [datasheet for PIC12F683](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41211D_.pdf), the max pull-up current is 400μA (see D070 on p.121).  The 25 PICs pulling up together would pull 10mA.

The nominal max GPIO sink current for this PIC is 8.5mA (see D080 on p.121), while the absolute max is 25mA.  There is also a more detailed chart fig.16-24 on p.149, which goes to 10mA.

You can make do [without a comfortable margin] using only internal pull-ups and not exceeding max sink current for a GPIO pin.  But I would use external pull-up resistors in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I have to disagree with the previous answers.
In the [PIC12F683 Datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41211D_.pdf) the typical pull-up current for 5V is given with typical 250μA and max. 400μA (see D080 on p.121). This lets you calculate the typical pull-up resistance to something around:

\$ R=\frac{U}{I}=\frac{5V}{250μA}=20k\Omega\$

And the minimum pull-up resistance to

\$ R=\frac{U}{I}=\frac{5V}{400μA}=12.5k\Omega\$

Assuming all pins are inputs, nothing will happen as the pull-up's will pull up against the input resistance (typical in the 2 digit Megaohms range). Basically no current will flow.

When some device drives this line to 0V there will also be no problem for your PIC's as each **individual** PIC will still have to source only typical

\$ I=\frac{U}{R}=\frac{5V}{20k\Omega}=250μA\$

and maximum

\$ I=\frac{U}{R}=\frac{5V}{12.5k\Omega}=400μA\$

However, whatever drives this line of 25 parallel PIC's to 0V will have to pull the signal down. To do that it must be able to drive:

25 pull-up's parallel will result in typical:

\$ R_{total}= \frac{1}{\frac{1}{20k\Omega}*25}=800\Omega\$

\$ I_{total}=\frac{U}{R_{total}}=\frac{5V}{800\Omega} = 6.25mA  \$ (or simple: 250μA x 25)

and maximum:

\$ R_{total}= \frac{1}{\frac{1}{12.5k\Omega}*25}=500\Omega\$

\$ I_{total}=\frac{U}{R_{total}}=\frac{5V}{500\Omega} = 10mA  \$ (or simple 400μA x 25)

In case GP4 and GP5 are connected as well (for whatever reason) the current will double to 12.5mA typical and 20mA max.

On page 115 of the same datasheet you can see that the max. sunk current per I/O Pin is 25mA. This means you can still drive the line of 25 pull-up's (or even 50 pull-up's in case GP4 and GP5 are connected) with a single output pin.

Comment: GP4 and GP5 are not connected together, they are two individual data lines.

Answer (score 1):

It will not create a short circuit condition because there is still a lot of resistance.
But yes, adding pull-ups resistors will increase current into the pin.

Assuming the internal pull-ups are around 10k and are the same value on each chip then you would have a load of around 400 Ohms (25 ICs).